# Azure Active Directory OAuth2 - how to restrict the delivery of tokens to unauthorized apps

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I'm trying to configure Active Directory to work in the following use case.

I have 1 API exposed in Azure API Management. I want this API to be called only by authorized apps.
I have created one AD App Registration representing this API and associated an App URI ID.
I have also created one AD App Registration representing my client app.

In POSTMAN, I use an OAuth2 client credentials grant type to get a token and it works. I have a token containing the right audience (= the application App URI ID of my API).

What is very weird is that I didn't do anything regarding permissions between the 2 AD apps. I thought that I need to authorize the client app to use the API app thanks to "API Permissions / Configured Permissions" but it sounds like it is not needed.

But it is not what I'm looking for because I want only authorized apps to be able to get a token with the right audience value.

Am I missing something in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

By default audience often means 'all APIs using an Authorization Server'. Some - but not all - vendors allow it to be customised in a more fine grained way.

Another option that is sometimes useful is to use custom scopes as high level privileges:

- UI 1 includes scope=Orders
- UI 2 includes scope=Reports
- API 1 requires scope=Orders
- If UI 2 calls API 1 you can deny access because it is missing a required scope

This can be a more flexible mechanism than audience, while achieving the same goals

It may not make sense if you are showing these details on consent screens to end users though ..

Answer (score 0):

I found how to proceed, here are the steps:

- In the Backend application, we need to set the User assignment required to true
- We then need to update manually the manifest of the Backend app to create "app roles". We can create multiple roles to act as "scopes"
- Then we need to set API Permissions in the AD Client App to authorize several app roles of the BackEnd App.

Thanks to this configuration, when the client App requests a token, it will obtain it if roles are authorized and the token will contain the list of roles if the "role" claim of the token.

Detail of the configuration is explained in the section of the post: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon#ensure-that-tokens-azure-ad-issues-tokens-for-your-web-api-only-to-allowed-clients